# Converting a string to a DateTime with more than 7 decimals of milliseconds

Tags: c#, datetime

So I am trying to convert a string date in the following format to a DateTime. I am able to parse it using ParseExact when there are 7 decimals of fractions of a second using the format string "fffffff", but the string I'm getting can (doesn't always) have 9 decimals of fractions of a second.

I don't really care what those last few digits are as I'm going to end up rounding it anyways. What I'm looking for is some way to either parse them or truncate them before I get an error from the ParseExact method because it doesn't match up with "fffffff". My only thought would be to truncate the string based on the number of characters after the decimal point. Is there an easier way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Sample string to parse: "2015-12-10 13:14:15.123456789"

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2015-12-10 13:14:15.123456789", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

throws a FormatException, but the following works.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2015-12-10 13:14:15.1234567", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "7 decimals of milliseconds" - there can be "7 decimal digits for fractions of a second" though.

Comment: We meant the same thing, I just couldn't come up with the correct phrasing. Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this with the normal parsing code and the existing text. `DateTime`'s precision only goes down to ticks, where a tick is 100 nanoseconds. I think the simplest thing to do is truncate the string itself:

```
string pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff";
if (text.Length > pattern.Length)
{
    text = text.Substring(0, pattern.Length);
}
DateTime value = DateTime.ParseExact(text, pattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Obligatory plug: in [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) 2.0 you won't need to do this as it supports a precision of nanoseconds :)

Comment: Jon, can you please show an example for this on Noda Time? Because it says `f, ff ... up to fffffff` in [Local-time patterns](http://nodatime.org/1.2.x/userguide/localtime-patterns.html) page. Little bit confused.

Comment: @SonerGönül: That's the 1.2.x user guide. Nanosecond precision is in the (unreleased) 2.0: http://nodatime.org/unstable/userguide/localtime-patterns.html

Answer (score 5):

To addition Jon's answer, `7` is the limit for parsing and represent significant digits of the seconds fraction.

From [The `"fffffff"` custom format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#fffffffSpecifier)

> Although it is *possible* to display the ten millionths of a second
>   component of a time value, **that value may not be meaningful**. The
>   precision of date and time values depends on the resolution of the
>   system clock. On the Windows NT 3.5 (and later) and Windows Vista
>   operating systems, the clock's resolution is approximately 10-15
>   milliseconds.